# Cómo hacer para abrir varios formularios y que no me salga un error de excepcion al momento de intentar abrirlos

Tags: c#

Tengo un form como menú principal. Dentro del form tengo un contenedor, donde se deben abrir todos los form; el problema es que abre el primero pero al intentar abrir los otros me sale un error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'No se puede obtener acceso al objeto desechado. Nombre del objeto: 'frmcategoria'.'

Este es el código

```
public partial class Inicio : Form
{
    private static  Usuario usuarioActual;
    private static IconMenuItem MenuActivo = null;
    private static Form FormularioActivo = null;

    public Inicio(Usuario objusuario)
    {
        usuarioActual = objusuario;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Inicio_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblnombre.Text = usuarioActual.NombreCompleto;
    }
    

    private void AbrirFormulario(IconMenuItem menu, Form Formulario) {
        if (MenuActivo != null) {
            MenuActivo.BackColor = Color.White;   
        }   
        menu.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        MenuActivo = menu;

        if (FormularioActivo != null){
            Formulario.Close();
        }
        FormularioActivo = Formulario;
        Formulario.TopLevel = false;
        Formulario.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        Formulario.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Formulario.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
        Contenedor.Controls.Add(Formulario);
        Formulario.Show();
    }

    private void menuusuario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AbrirFormulario((IconMenuItem)sender, new frmusuario());
    }

    private void SubMenuCategoria_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AbrirFormulario(menuajustes, new frmcategoria());
    }

    private void SubMenuProducto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AbrirFormulario(menuajustes, new frmproducto());
    }

    private void SubmenuVenta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AbrirFormulario(menuventas, new frmventas());
    }

    private void SubMenuDetalleVenta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AbrirFormulario(menuventas, new frmdetalleventas());
    }
}
```

El programa se detiene justo en esta línea de código `Formulario.Show()`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! aca lo cerraste.. no entiendo que esperabas hacer: if (FormularioActivo != null){
            Formulario.Close();
        }

Comment: para mi, querias cerrar formularioactivo, no formulario...